# Flutter App not installing after name change

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have recently changed my package name and updated it everywhere in the whole project . The build is coming successful but its not installing . Its an android application. Please help

Comment: Do you get an error message? Can you share it?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your help